# Why doesn't the vertical scrollbar work in Outlook's message list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

Moving the scrollbar handle in Outlook 2007's message list doesn't scroll the messages until I let go of the handle. Can I change this behavior? It's pretty annoying, and makes the scrollbar kinda useless.

Comment: Would you be able to show us a screenshot with a helpful arrow to show us which scroll bar you are talking about. If I remember correctly, there are a few scroll bars. (Only asking this to help support your answer.)

Comment: There's only one scroll bar that scrolls the messages. Note the plural.

Answer (score 8):

Unbelievably, this appalling Outlook 2007 defect is still present in Outlook 2010. And still present in Outlook 2013. **EDIT**: and still there in 2016, and still there in 365 as of January 2017. **EDIT**: and *still* there in 365 as of January *2019*.

And even if I drag the scrollbar to the bottom of the list and back, it doesn't make subsequent scrolling work. No scrolling in lists of messages--just a jump to the place where you release the mouse.

The only time scrolling works is when the list contains only about 30 messages so only just goes off the screen. *The one time you hardly need scrolling!*

**However**, for those of us who happen to appreciate trackpoint scrolling, and who therefore use a keyboard sporting this feature, there's a surprise answer: for some reason trackpoint scrolling makes even Outlook lists scroll! Joy.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, I was surprised to see that I could duplicate this.

Seems like the only way the scroll bar starts working properly is to do the following:

1. Select whatever folder you want to see (ie Inbox)
2. Drag the scroll bar to the absolute bottom of the list
3. Scroll bar seems to work properly now

Very, very strange. Maybe someone should file a bug with MS and hopefully we will see a fix for this?

I agree that this can't be the intended behavior.

**Edit:** Scrolling with the mousewheel is probably the best workaround overall.

Comment: Nope... That doesn't work for me. And the mousewheel doesn't let me scroll quickly to the area of the message I'm looking for and then slowly scan for it. As for reporting bugs to MS, I tried that before. I'm willing to let others waste their time now.